# Providing initial data into sql tables using sql file inside the sql folder of app is not working in django1.9

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django

In older django versions I use to load the default values using sql files which are in the folder sql in side the app directory. But in django.1.9c1 it's not working. 
   When I look at django documentation it seems like support raw sql file is removed to load the default data. 
  How to load the dafault data using  raw sql queries into tables in django.

What is django management command for loading initial data(not fixures or JSON) into tables using raw sql files(queries)

Answer (score 0):

As the [deprecation timeline says](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/internals/deprecation/#deprecation-removed-in-1-9), support for automatic loading of initial_data fixtures and initial SQL data was removed in Django 1.9.

For Django 1.7+, the recommended way to load data is to create a [data migration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/migrations/#data-migrations). If you have raw SQL statements to add data, you could use [`RunSQL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/migration-operations/#runsql) in you migrations to run these.